# Shield observable chain

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have this RxJS observable chain. I want to remove final error handling (since there is some error handling in chain which I need there) from chain and leave it to Global error handler. Whatever I tried to do, when error is returned from http call, subscription is canceled.
So I want to leave error handling to global error handler and to keep subscription active.

```
// onUpdateScale$ is Observable 

this.onUpdateScale$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.svc.update(this.getUpdateRequest()).pipe( // http call
        catchError(err => {
            this.mbs.dispatchEvent(this.events.udateScaleFailed);
            console.log(err);     /// I want to remove this since proper error handling is in global error handler.
            return of(undefined); /// also, here I want this:  return throwError(() => error)
        }),                                         ///
        filter(data => {                            /// And remove this since it would be unnecessary
            return data != undefined;               /// 
        })                                          ///
    ))
).subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
        .. do something
    }
});
```

Comment: I guess it is not possible to keep HTTP call active since it is internally autocompleted after getting any response from an API.
But onUpdateScale$ subscription won't be completed on the http error.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jsmyxd check this out

Comment: There is a way with retry() to keep observable subscribed, but then for some reason error is not propagated to the global error handler. Maybe this is not possible, but that would be quite weird, since you are forced to handle that type or errors separately from global error handler.
While I was writing this I figured out I could make some function that will do same thing as global error handler and call it, but all of this looks like duck-taping to me.